# Styling the vertical scrollbar only, in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

I have lots of contents that scrolls vertically on my website, but since everybody has a scrollwheel nowadays, I decided to make the scrollbar thinner, with that code:

```
.my-div { //Firefox
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
.my-div::-webkit-scrollbar { // chrom*
  width: 6px;
}
```

It works well, the scrollbar appear thin and nice. But I also a few divs have some horizontal scroll, and considering that most users don't have horizontal wheels and don't know the shift-scroll shortcut, they'll have to click on the scrollbar. Which is why I'd like the horizontal scrollbar to still be big.

For chrome based browsers, since I only set the width, it only applies to the vertical one and the horizontal one is still big, nice.

But for firefox, I can't find a way to only target one of the scrollbars. It there any way to do it (beside having to nested divs, one scrolling horizaontally without the css property, and one vertically with the property)?

Thanks